# Get values of multiple mat-form-fields

Tags: angular, mat-select, mat-form-field

I have the following code in .html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Min</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="options" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="{ min: number}">
      {{ number }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Max</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="options" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="{ max: number}">
      {{ number }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

When I open the dialog to read the results, I always receive result only for the max value.

```
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((response) => {
            if (response) {
              console.log(response);
}
});
```

How can I read both min and max values on afterClosed()?

Comment: Change your `[formControl]` names to "options" and "options2". Both form elements are using the same variable.

Comment: @YSFKBDY I changed options of the second mat-select to options2. Now, in the response I receive only the answer for the first mat-select (i.e. for options) :\

Comment: Did you define options2 like options in your backend code?

Comment: @YSFKBDY yes, on .ts file I have the declarations:  options = new FormControl('');
  options2 = new FormControl('');

Comment: @YSFKBDY I'm sorry. I hadn't changed the data submitted after pressing ok button:   <button
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
    [mat-dialog-close]="{options, options2}"
  >
    OK
  </button> . Now, it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!